# Bash redirection combined with "double pipe" notation

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

Is it possible to combine redirecting output to a file and pipes with ||? (Not sure what this is called)

Example:

```
(wget -qO- example.com/duff || exit) | some_processing >> outfile.txt
```

If wget fails, I would like to exit and not run some_processing or create the blank file.

Comment: I assume this needs to be a one-liner?

Comment: It would be nice, but other solutions gladly accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=`wget -qO- example.com/duff`

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
  echo $RESULT | some_processing >> outfile.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

`||` is a logical or.  Not creating `outfile.txt` would take much more complex syntax; as you have it written (the normal way), `outfile.txt` is created even before `wget` is run.

I can't honestly think of any way to force the pipe not to happen at all if the left-hand command fails.  I'd just write a Perl script if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

> ([ $? -eq 0 ] && some_processing >> outfile.txt) <<< $(wget -qO- example.com/duff)

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much answer how to do it.

> If wget fails, I would like to exit and not run some_processing or create the blank file.

---

wget wget -qO- example.com/duff

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]   //$? means return value, on well written programs this should be zero

then

```
some_processing >> outfile.txt
```

fi

---

I think this will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it may not be enough to check for return code. it might be good to also check for return HTTP status such as 404 ..... etc